# Simply / condense this code?

Tags: jquery, each

I often find myself writing two blocks of code — one for the init and the same for on change, like below. Suggestions for a more condensed / elegant approach?

```
$( '.some-class' ).each(function(){
    var title = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
    $( this ).attr('title', title);
});
$( '.some-class' ).change(function(){
    var title = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
    $( this ).attr('title', title);
});
```

Comment: you could just trigger change event once bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function doSomething (){
    var title = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
    $( this ).attr('title', title);
}

$( '.some-class' ).each(doSomething);
$( '.some-class' ).change(doSomething);
```

Perhaps?

Comment: Thanks... so obvious that my brain couldn't see it! Thanks again.